# Retrieve from database, calculate and post to the view

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to calculate the difference between two dates and post the result to the view.  The table contains the following rows:

> Id, AuthorId, duedate,body

I know how to calculate the difference between two dates, but this is for a single row.  Now, I'm pulling multiple rows from the database, and according to laravel I'm not supposed to perform any calculation in the view.

Below is from the controller:

```
 public function index()
{
    //

    $posts = Post::all();
    $to = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $from = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', '2015-5-6 9:30:34');

    $diff_in_days = $to->diffInDays($from);

    return view('blog.index',['posts'=>$posts,'diffdays'=>$diff_in_days]);
}
```

I just used a dummy date for the `$from` variable.  It's supposed to be replaced with the due datedate value from the database.  I am not sure how to approach so I can perform the calculation in the controller before passing it to the view.
I'm still learning laravel, any help will be great.

Comment: Do you want to calculate when a post was created? for example '3 days ago'?

Comment: If the data comes from the database, it might be easier to add a column to the results using for example `DATEDIFF()` to get the difference in days between two dates.

Comment: @jeroen I thought about doing it that way, but it means I would need to automatically update that column every single that passess. will that be best practice ?

Comment: @LeventeOtta I want to calculate the number of days left before the due date

Comment: No, I don't mean adding a column to the database, just a calculated column to the result set.

Comment: You shouldn't calculate this. Carbon can do it easily for you. Let me write an answer

Comment: @LeventeOtta Thanks

Comment: @jeroen let's day as of today, there's 10 days left. then I store that in the calculated column. Tomorrow it will be 9 days left. I will then need to update the database with the value 9. I'm not sure if this will be the best way to do this or I might be misunderstanding you

Comment: You should only store the due-date and in for example mysql you do something like `SELECT *, DATEDIFF(\`due_date\`, NOW()) AS days_due FROM ...`. Easier and probably a lot more efficient than doing in in PHP. So you don't update your database, you calculate when you select the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `duedate` is astandard `dateTime` column and if you've added `duedate` to the [`$dates`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) array:

```
protected $dates = ['duedate', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

If it's not, [create an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for the date to convert a custom date string to a Carbon instance.

Then you can just do this in a view:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->duedate->diffInDays() }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Yes, duedate is standard dateTime column, but I haven't added it to the dates.  Because I retrieving a bunch of rows from the database, how will I go about adding duedate to the $dates array ?

Comment: @user1783675 if you'll add it to the array in the model then `duedate` property will be automatically converted to a Carbon instance by Laravel. Laravel does the same with the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns by default.

Answer (score 2):

If `duedate` is astandard dateTime column and if you've added duedate to the `$dates` array in your model:

`protected $dates = ['duedate'];`

Now `duedate` is casted to timestamp so you can use Carbon\Carbon methods on this variable.

Let see what you need in controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('blog.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

Then you can just do this in a view:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->duedate->diffForHumans() }}
@endforeach
```

---

Tested in artisan tinker:

Days:

```
>>> $now = Carbon\Carbon::now()->addWeek()
=> Carbon\Carbon @1520345864 {#814
     date: 2018-03-06 15:17:44.571132 Europe/Budapest (+01:00),
   }
>>> $now->diffForHumans();
=> "6 days from now"
```

Hours:

```
>>> $now = Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDay()
=> Carbon\Carbon @1519827379 {#811
     date: 2018-02-28 15:16:19.447731 Europe/Budapest (+01:00),
   }
>>> $now->diffForHumans();
=> "23 hours from now"
```